# Calling a methods on the delegate directly from a button, Is that a good practice?

Tags: ios, delegates

This controller has a child controller that implements a Delegate protocol with few methods.

```
ParentController : UIViewController <ChildControllerDelegate>
```

The Parent controller has a method that is called from within itself (lets call it `doSomething`).

Now, I need to call this `doSomething` method from a button inside the the child-controller. So I can think of 3 options:

1. Adding a method to the protocol `pleaseCallDoSomething` and calling this method from the button, then implement this `pleaseCallDoSomething` method in the parent view controller, and lastly call the `doSomething` inside the `pleaseCallDoSomething`.
2. The second option is not to register a new method in the child view protocol and simply use:

   ```
   [btn addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(doSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   ```
3. Adding a `doSomething` method to the protocol and implement it on the parent view controller, and then inside the parent view controller call it locally when I need it. (I mean calling a delegate method from the delegate and locally).

What will be the best practice?

Thanks
Shani

Comment: Number one incurs the overhead of two message sends, number two is extremely efficient, and number 3 goes against the basic rules of delegation.  Tl;dr: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not bind your delegate as target of your button. Your delegate property is most likely declared weak to avoid retain-cycles. If you assign it as target you will get a retain-cycle, and as long as you do not remove the button, your whole object-hierarchy will never be deallocated.

parent<--strong-->child<--weak-->parent

parent<--strong-->button

after target assign

parent<--strong-->child<--strong-->button<--strong-->parent

Also your button should not know anything about the controller hierarchy, so i think it is bad MVC to let your views communicate with other objects than the controller they origin. This will always let to trouble sooner or later.

Comment: Agreed. #1 is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is excellent practice to call delegate methods directly from UIControlEvents.  It is the basic equivalent of a msg_send anyhow, seeing as the the button builds a call from your target and selector arguments.  and it doesn't incur the slight penalty that calling a middleman method would cause, thus eliminating overhead.